# How do i use a conditional statement to style a react anchorlink tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

i am trying to style my anchorlink tags for navigation using a conditional statement while also adding the hover and transition effect, it seems i am not getting the syntax right.

i want to apply the styling effect if the selected page matches the id of the navlink which will be in lower case, here is a snippet of what it looks like below

```
import AnchorLink from "react-anchor-link-smooth-scroll"


interface Props  {
    page: string;
    selectedPage: string;
    setSelectedPage: (value:string) => void;
}

function Link({page,selectedPage,setSelectedPage}: Props) {
    const lowerCasePage = page.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, "")
  return (
    <AnchorLink
    className={'${selectedPage === lowerCasePage ? "text-primary-500" : ""}
    transition duration-500 hover:text-primary-300
    '}
    href={'#${lowerCasePage}'}
    onClick={() => setSelectedPage(lowerCasePage)}
    >
        {page}
    </AnchorLink>
  )
}

export default Link
```

Comment: as you are passing className prop to <AnchorLink> Component>. The anchorLink component should use this className to its nested element className to apply the styles you wanted.

Please provide details about the AnchorLink component for more clarity

Comment: the amount of errors i am getting is overwhelming, it has got to be a syntax issue maybe there is a tag i didn't close properly

Comment: Can you put this in a code sandbox snippet so we can see your errors too?

Comment: It looks like you are using apostrophes where you should be using backticks.  See this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: You've a typo in your code, using regular single quotes instead of backticks for the string template. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Comment: Yes it was definitely a typo, I have fixed it now thank you

Answer (score -1):

You are using template literals incorrectly in your className prop. You should use backticks (`) to define the template literal.

```
<AnchorLink
  className={`${
    selectedPage === lowerCasePage ? "text-primary-500" : ""
  } transition duration-500 hover:text-primary-300`}
  href={`#${lowerCasePage}`}
  onClick={() => setSelectedPage(lowerCasePage)}
>
  {page}
</AnchorLink>
```